# Open a website from a record using Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Just need your help with regards to Lightning Component. My goal is to open a link using a button, right now I can open a link via button but it's only has a static value, what I need is to open the link set in the Website field in the Account Object. Here's the code that I have so far.

CMP

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
<ui:button label="Open in New window" press="{!c.openActionWindow}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
openActionWindow : function(component, event, helper) {
window.open("https://www.google.com");
}
})
```

I've been looking for different websites on how to get a field value. Thank you so much and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use ui:button. It is obsolete and will not work sometime next year. Use a button or lightning:button instead.

Second, you need to load the data. You do this with force:recordData.

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId">
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
  <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetFields="{!v.record}" field="Name,Whatever" />
```

Then, in your handler, get the record and use the value you want:

```
openActionWindow : function(component, event, helper) {
  var record = component.get("v.record");
  window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+encodeURIComponent(record.Whatever));
}
```

Comment: appreciate your quick response, I think I'm almost there. The only problem now is that I need to open links outside Salesforce. For example the field value us www.facebook.com. I need to open facebook.com via button click. Thank you

Comment: @NaofumiKun It should be possible to do so onclick.

Comment: Yes, I already added a Lightning button to have an Onclick. My problem is the link that's opening in a new tab is https://sample.my.salesforce.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F. My goal is only www.facebook.com which is the Website field value. Thank you

Comment: I already made it window.open("https://"+encodeURIComponent(record.Website)), but it's still not working

Comment: Got it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to perform this from a hyperlink custom formula field on the record, rather than a lightning component.

```
HYPERLINK("www.google.com", "Click to open Google!")
```